# How to change values of rows based on conditions in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe that is shown below,

```
    type  label
0      0      0
1      0      0
2      0      0
3      0      0
4      2      1
5      2      1
6      2      1
7      2      1
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     0      0
11     0      0
12     0      0
13     0      0
14     0      0
15     0      0
16     0      0
17     0      0
18     0      0
19     0      0
```

**(Need some magic to be done)**

The change should be made in type column such that, in a row if `label` is `0` and `type` is `0` then next row of `type` should be assigned `2`.

Full dataframe should look like this:

```
    type  label
0      0      0
1      2      0
2      2      0
3      0      0
4      2      1
5      2      1
6      2      1
7      2      1
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     0      0
11     2      0
12     2      0
13     2      0
14     2      0
15     2      0
16     2      0
17     2      0
18     2      0
19     2      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to mask row which has `type` and `label` columns value is 0 and [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to shift index by desired number of periods with an optional time freq.

**Ex.**

```
m = df['type'].eq(0) & df['label'].eq(0)
df.loc[m == m.shift(1),'type'] = 2
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

```
    type  label
0      0      0
1      2      0
2      2      0
3      2      0
4      2      1
5      2      1
6      2      1
7      2      1
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     0      0
11     2      0
12     2      0
13     2      0
14     2      0
15     2      0
16     2      0
17     2      0
18     2      0
19     2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach

```
df['Condition']=(df==0).all(axis=1)
df['Condition']=df['Condition'].shift(periods=1).fillna(False)
df['Type'] = np.where(df['Condition'], 2, df['Type'])

Type  label  Condition
0      0      0      False
1      2      0       True
2      2      0       True
3      2      0       True
4      2      1       True
5      2      1      False
6      2      1      False
7      2      1      False
8      2      1      False
9      2      1      False
10     0      0      False
11     2      0       True
12     2      0       True
13     2      0       True
14     2      0       True
15     2      0       True
16     2      0       True
17     2      0       True
18     2      0       True
19     2      0       True
```